# WPF application with multi Icon

Tags: wpf, windows, icons

i have tried to make a wpf application with blinking icon with below steps:

1. set Icon1.ico as the application icon in project properties
2. create a DispatcherTimer
3. add a function to DispatcherTimer
4. in the function check icon name and change it

the code is like this

```
private void ToggleIconVisibility(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (((BitmapImage)Icon).UriSource.OriginalString.CompareTo("Icon1.ico") == 0)
        {
            Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Icon2.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
        else
        {
            Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Icon1.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
```

it works well when i run it in visual studio, but after publishing application could not find Icon2 and crashed. both icon files are located in the root folder of project.
I would be appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Did you include your icons as resources into the application?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're expecting icon to be or what other code you have.

When I just set the icon in the app that didn't work for me with your code.

I therefore added an int to flag which icon is expected to be current.

I set my two icon files as content, copy if newer.

Which means they're copied alongside the exe.

This code then works for me:

```
    private int currentIcon = 1;
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (currentIcon ==1 )
        {
            Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Icon2.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
            currentIcon = 2;
            return;
        }

        Icon = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Icon1.ico", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        currentIcon = 1;
    }
```